# Why Rename in C not working correctly?

Tags: c

It was working correctly a while ago. But i dont know what was is the error.

My Code:

```
char oldfn[] = "d://booksdata.txt";
char newfn[] = "d://booksdata_temp.txt";
remove(oldfn);
rename(newfn, oldfn);
```

Remove function works correctly but my rename function does not work.

Comment: same here. we also don't know `what is the error`.

Comment: What error do you get? If you are working on Windows, I believe that `"d://booksdata.txt"` should be `"D:\\booksdata.txt`.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Actually, Windows is perfectly happy with the `/` to separate directories, and the double `//` is ugly but harmless. That is using the API. If you use Windows command line utilities, then you'll have some pain.

Comment: well they dont work, if they do work but in the wrong way

Comment: Check that `remove` & `rename` succeeded (gave 0) and use `perror` on failure

Comment: permission denied- is the error I am facing

Answer (score 3):

From ISO/IEC9899:

> 7.19.4.2 The rename function
>
> Synopsis
>
> 1 `#include < stdio.h>`
>
> `int rename(const char *old, const char *new);`

As you can see by the prototype: you are using the old and new arguments in the wrong place.

Just switch then and one error is fixed.
If there is still one... Tell us the error text please.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the `rename()` call backwards. It should be:

```
rename(oldfn, newfn);
```

Although it wouldn't hurt to have copied the error message in the first place!

Comment: @DuaaaLord: Well you are doing it again, you are not giving information. Saying _doesnt rename file_ is not useful. You are not helping us help you!

Comment: @DuaaaLord: Well, maybe you don't have permissions. Have you checked if you can rename this file from the command line, with the same user?

Comment: Or if it is a embeded execution, maybe the user who invokes the pseudo suer who invokes the execution has no write rights?