# Rename Function Not working in C

Tags: c

I have created a function which updates value of file and then renames it.
My Code:

```
void UpdateBooks()
{
system("CLS");
char *update[5] = {malloc(30),malloc(30),malloc(30),malloc(30),malloc(30)};
int coop = 0;
struct Books book;
char oldfn[] = "d:/booksdata.txt";
char newfn[] = "d:/booksdata_temp.txt";
int deletecheck = 0;
char *myisbnumber = malloc(4);
char line[256];
char * pch;
int countcheck = 0;
allocatebooks(&book);
fp = fopen(oldfn,"r");
fpa = fopen(newfn,"w+");
if (fp == NULL || fpa == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    exit(1);
}
printf("Enter ISBN Number Of The Book You Want To Update:\n");
scanf("%10s",myisbnumber);

while (fgets(line,sizeof line,fp) != NULL)
{
    pch = strtok (line,",");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
    if(countcheck == 0)
        book.name = pch;
    else if(countcheck == 1)
        book.author = pch;
    else if(countcheck == 2)
        book.bookserialnumber = pch;
    else if(countcheck == 3)
        book.isbnnumber = pch;
    else if(countcheck == 4)
        book.edition = pch;
    else if(countcheck == 5)
        book.is_reserved = pch;
    pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
    countcheck++;
    }
    if(strcmp(myisbnumber,book.isbnnumber) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(fpa,"%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,\n",book.name,book.author,book.bookserialnumber,book.isbnnumber,book.edition,book.is_reserved);
    }
    else
    {
        deletecheck++;
        RedoUpdate:
        system("CLS");
        coop = 0;
        printf("What do you want to Update:\n");
        printf("1.Name\t  %s\n2.Author\t  %s\n3.Serial Number\t  %s\n4.Edition\t  %s\n5.Is_Reserved\t  %s\n6.Nothing to Update\n",book.name,book.author,book.bookserialnumber,book.edition,book.is_reserved);
        scanf("%d",&coop);
        if(coop > 0 && coop <= 5)
        {
            printf("Enter New Value\n");
            scanf("%s",update[coop]);
            if(coop == 1)
                book.name = update[coop];
            else if(coop == 2)
                book.author = update[coop];
            else if(coop == 3)
                book.bookserialnumber = update[coop];
            else if(coop == 4)
                book.edition = update[coop];
            else if(coop == 5)
                book.is_reserved = update[coop];
            goto RedoUpdate;
        }
        fprintf(fpa,"%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,\n",book.name,book.author,book.bookserialnumber,book.isbnnumber,book.edition,book.is_reserved);
        printf("Updated!\n");
    }
    countcheck = 0;
}
if(deletecheck == 0)
    goto END;
if(fclose(fp) != 0)
    perror("File Not Closed FP\n");
if(fclose(fpa) != 0)
    perror("File Not Closed FPA\n");
if(remove(oldfn) == -1)
{
    perror("Remove Error");
    exit(1);
}
if(rename(newfn,oldfn) == -1)
{
    perror("Rename Error");
    exit(1);
}
printf("Completed!\n");
END:
getch();
}
```

The whole code Works correctly. I also Close file with fclose but when I try to rename it I get Permission Denied error.
when using rename(newfn,oldfn) I get : permission denied error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Rename in C not working correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27251379/why-rename-in-c-not-working-correctly)

Comment: Just by the way: You should check your update array for malloc did not return NULL.

Comment: `char *myisbnumber = malloc(4);` very small.

Comment: "The whole code Works correctly" Ah, no. There are serious issues with your code, for example using `scanf` to read up to 10 characters into a 4-byte buffer (`myisbnumber`).

Comment: actually everything works okay my real issue is with renaming

Comment: Your real issue is your mucus-ridden coding styl, which this code tells me you should obvious change. In addition: Your Question got multiple times answered in this thread by the answer + comments, as also in the duplicate I linked by the answers + comments. Why you ask a question if you dont care on the answer? Do you expect the problem will fix it self if you just ask the question frequently enough? Or do you really expect us to fix your code and present you a fixed code as answer?

Comment: Actually I am just a student hence i have alot to learn. I did check the duplicate question which matched mine. That person must be a classmate of mine as this is a class assignment. Secondly I do care for the answer which solves my problem not for those who bring up more question

Comment: What are the permissions of the newly created file? Maybe the directory has settings so that you aren't allowed to rename it. Does it work if you use `c:/temp` instead of `d:/`?

Answer (score 0):

The `remove` - `rename` code looks fine. There are some other issues with the code, most notably the buffer overrun of `myisbnumber` pointed out by  Andrew Medico. You should fix this one!

There is also a memory leak since you never free any of the memory you `malloc` - you should consider allocating them as normal arrays instead. The stack should be able to handle the extra 154 bytes (161 if you change `myisbnumber` to `char myisbnumber[11]`).

However, I don't think either of those is causing your problems (although you can never be sure about the first one, since it causes undefined behaviour). I think the problem is due to file permissions (inherited from the directory).

The path indicates that you are working in Windows.
You should check the permissions of the newly created file. The directory may have settings so that you aren't allowed to rename the file. If that is the case you can solve your problem by either changing the directory permissions or by using a directory where you have full access.

Comment: tried ur way Code before Removing got File Exist Error.

Comment: tried after removing got No File Exist in Directory

Comment: Answer rewritten - first version was just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From ISO/IEC9899:

> 7.19.4.2 The rename function
>
> Synopsis
>
> 1 `#include <stdio.h>`
>
> `int rename(const char *old, const char *new);`

As you can see by the prototype: you are using the old and new arguments in the wrong place.

Comment: Actually he isn't. `newfn` is a temp name and he wants to rename it to `oldfn` after removing the old `oldfn`.

Answer (score -1):

close the file using fclose() before renaming the file

Comment: As the source shows, the OP did so.